# Switched to Code Blocks from c++ with updated gcc compiler which causes errors in my source code that compiled fine with the old gcc compiler v3

Tags: c++, casting, mingw, codeblocks

The problem is below:

```
SendMessage(hwnd_SSMAIN_PARENTCONTAINER_RTFCONTROL,WM_SETTEXT,(WPARAM)0,(LPARAM&)webfilebuffer.str());
```

1. hwnd_SSMAIN_PARENTCONTAINER_RTFCONTROL is an handle to an rtf control
2. webfilebuffer is type stringstream

and compiles fine within dev c++ with an older version of gcc.

I just now updated to code blocks and used the import command from the file menu for dev c++ projects.

Now within code blocks I get this error for the send message above:

E:\Projects\PWS Source Studio 7-18-12\open-save-new dialog.h|94|error: invalid cast of an rvalue expression of type 'std::basic_stringstream::__string_type {aka std::basic_string}' to type 'LPARAM& {aka long int&}'|

I just now started to use the newer version of the gcc MinGW.

I looked this error up online and found nothing about it, if I just look up "invalid cast of an rvalue expression of type " instead of "invalid cast of an rvalue expression of type 'std::basic_stringstream::__string_type {aka std::basic_string}' to type 'LPARAM& {aka long int&}'|"

I find a couple of things on google which I tried to do that line above but it seems like no matter what I try to do it doesn't work.

From the looks of it I can no longer convert the str to lparam and that it will only accept lparam for now own ie it must be something like  LPARAM something;

instead of string something; and then converting that to lparam for send message to accept this.

Can someone please explain to me what is going on and what I need to do to get this to work?

Thank you

Comment: What is `SendMessage`?

Comment: I would allocate a character buffer of the appropriate type, probably wchar_t and then copy the string into it then pass the address of the character buffer as the LPARAM argument.  Normally LPARAM would be the address of the string buffer to send to the control and you would want to provide it in as simple a form as possible.

Comment: @C.R. SendMessage() is a Windows API call to send a message to a window by specifying the window handle of the window to receive the message along with a message identifier followed by two parameters which tend to be addresses of parameters or additional 32 bit values.

Comment: Actually not sure why you specify (LPARAM &) rather than a cast to LPARAM as in (LPARAM)webfilebuffer.str() and is it a wchar_t or char string?

Comment: At the time I had a hard time to get send message to send the text within the string stream to the rtf control and someone replied back that I need the & after lparam for it to send the string to the rtf control.

Comment: question title too short (NO). What do you mean by "switching fron CodeBlocks to C++"? That's comparing apples with oranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way

```
SendMessage(hwnd_SSMAIN_PARENTCONTAINER_RTFCONTROL,WM_SETTEXT,(WPARAM)0, 
    (LPARAM)webfilebuffer.str().c_str());
```

This code converts a char* to an LPARAM, which should be legal.

You will have to change the code that receives the message too. Post that code if you need help with that.

Comment: I tried that when I looked up the error from google, It still gave me same error instead of it being converted to string it says something about c_char. I'm installing some updates on my pc so once thats done i'll try that again and see what it says.

Again thanks everyone

Comment: Thank you John for your help. Reason why I was getting a problem was an out of case error that was effecting that line because of an added bracket. Now it works fine other then me having to change the way the webfilebuffer was working.

Sorry that it took me a while to reply, just been busy with life and all.

again thank you and everyone who has helped me out. It compiles in code blocks now and even faster and better so idk why I haven't used this in the first place. Code folding also saves me a lot of time :)